# Regex: Getting text in between time stamps

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to get the sample text in between the two timestamps in the image below?

```
string=[3/24/17, 8:34:00 PM] Hello [3/24/17, 8:35:22 PM] THIS TEXT [3/24/17, 8:39:07 PM] Bye [3/24/17, 8:39:19 PM]
```

Using the Regex =  `(\[.*?\](.*?)\[.*?\])`

I am only able to get `Hello` and `Bye`

What can I do to get the text in between the second and third time stamps.

Comment: So you want to get ``Hello`` ?

Comment: Probably something like: `(?<=] ).*?(?= \[)`

Comment: Maybe try matching just the end of the time text - not the whole block in square braces.. what's happening is you're consuming too much text and it won't be able to match the next immediate set of words between dates. @Joaosl

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how rigorous you want the matching to be, this one is a bit restrictive.

```
>>> regex = r"""
...         \d+:\d+:\d+\s[AP]M\]    # Match end time text.
...         \s*(.*?)\s*             # Group text between time and date, excluding spaces on each end.
...         \[\d+/\d+/\d+           # Match begin date text.
...         """
>>> 
>>> re.findall(regex, string, flags=re.VERBOSE)
['Hello', 'THIS TEXT', 'Bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match letters with [A-Z]:

```
string = '[3/24/17, 8:34:00 PM] Hello [3/24/17, 8:35:22 PM] THIS TEXT [3/24/17, 8:39:07 PM] Bye [3/24/17, 8:39:19 PM]'
print(re.findall(' ([a-z A-Z]+) ', string))
# ['Hello', 'THIS TEXT', 'Bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `re.split` with the regex pattern `\s*\[.*?\]\s*`, to split the input on the timestamps, leaving behind the text you want to match, as separate entries in a list.  I also filter off empty string elements, to deal with edge cases where the string may start or end with timestamp (which would generate an empty string match on the left/right).

```
string = "[3/24/17, 8:34:00 PM] Hello [3/24/17, 8:35:22 PM] THIS TEXT [3/24/17, 8:39:07 PM] Bye [3/24/17, 8:39:19 PM]"
parts = re.split(r'\s*\[.*?\]\s*', string)
parts = filter(None, parts)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['Hello', 'THIS TEXT', 'Bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` with lazy quantifier (?) to match between ] and [:

```
s = "[3/24/17, 8:34:00 PM] Hello [3/24/17, 8:35:22 PM] THIS TEXT [3/24/17, 8:39:07 PM] Bye [3/24/17, 8:39:19 PM]"
m = re.findall('\]\s(.*?)\s\[', s)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'THIS TEXT', 'Bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your regex is
python searches in linear pastern

```
[date]first[date2]second[date3]third[date4]
```

here when `first` is found then date1 and date2 are processed 
so processing will start from `second`
hence python won't find `second`.
As it doesn't fit in `[date]text[date]`.

IMHO you can try one of two things

1. `(.*?\](.*?)\[.*?)`  search things between square bracket
2. `(\[.*?\](.*?))`     search string post date.